# Rails, managing history of model updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates, updatemodel

I'm not sure what's the best approach in my situation, I would like an opinion.

My situation is:

I have a "`Ticket`" model, having several fields of many kinds: text, numerical and associations. Tickets support comments through the `acts_as_commentable` gem.

The `tickets` are generated by users, who can comment and modify their own tickets.

Because the fields of a `ticket` can change over time I would like to allow my users to modify several of them. What I need though is to keep a commented history of all the changes, so that at any moment they can see in a ticket what, why and when was changed, in the comment, timestamp and list of changes that they can see together with the comment.

I was thinking to solve this by generating a "`TicketUpdate`" model, have the TicketUpdates generated in the Comments form (using `fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`).

Basically the user could select in a drop down list (i.e. a `select` tag) the field they want to change, changing the value of the drop down would trigger an event to show an appropriate input field (`input` for the text and numeric fields, `select` for the associations) with the old value pre-populated

I could intercept the `TicketUpdates` in the "`comment/create`" controller performing the updates.

This approach would look nice and sweet to the user, but I don't see how to implement in a neat or DRY way. 
Because ticket has many fields and they are mixed decimals and associations, I would have to implement specific logic for each field, both in the view and in the controller.

I'm not sure if there's maybe a better approach, or there's actually any gem or trick to get this done easily.

anyone got anything to recommend me here?

I'm using rails 3.2.8.

Comment: try this `gem 'paper_trail'` https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: great idea, thanks I didn't know that, this seems to be like a big help for me.

Comment: Ok, that's really an interesting Gem. I've created a function to dig out what changed between two versions of my `ticket`, although I'm not sure how to link the versions to a comment, in My requirements I have that each change to the Tickets must have a comment (the user must motivate the change). 

I'm not sure how to have that done, the nested form with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` doesn't seem to work, because the comments are inserted with `acts_as_commentable` gem.

Comment: and exactly what version number you want to link to the comment? I am not really clear what comments has to do with versions. Please explain   how this should work

Comment: start posting files of your app, controllers, views and a good description to them as this probably will make it clear how it should work.